# How to remove prefix from multiple files in a directory

Tags: find

I have ~250 files with the name:

```
no_responseEvent_2002.02.07.03.15.56.970/       
no_responseEvent_2002.02.10.01.47.07.450/       
no_responseEvent_2002.02.13.14.18.46.00/
```

I want to remove 'no_response' from each file name.

How do I do that?
I know a for loop could work, but I am confused about how to implement it.

Comment: Build a Directory listing in your for loop and use the following: 
mv $f $(echo $f | sed -e 's/no_responseEvent//')` where `$f` is your directory listing.  I'd agree with Don here, but the files don't all have the same extension, therefore this is not a duplcate.

Comment: If you're using Debian/Ubuntu you can use the Perl based `rename` command which has a powerful regular expression feature.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I assume all the 250 files are in the same directory and follow the same naming pattern. If that is the case, you could  do,

```
for i in  "$remove"*;do mv "$i" "${i#"$remove"}";done
```

**Testing**

```
ls
no_responseEvent_2002.02.07.03.15.56.970   
no_responseEvent_2002.02.07.03.15.56.972
no_responseEvent_2002.02.07.03.15.56.971  
no_responseEvent_2002.02.07.03.15.56.973
```

Now, after I run the `for` loop, I get the output as,

```
remove=no_response
for i in  "$remove"*;do mv "$i" "${i#"$remove"}";done
ls
Event_2002.02.07.03.15.56.970  
Event_2002.02.07.03.15.56.971  
Event_2002.02.07.03.15.56.972  
Event_2002.02.07.03.15.56.973
```

**References**

http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2519/uniformly-correct-filenames-in-a-directory

Comment: Or simply, `"${i/no_response/}"`...